# Solving integrals of an undefined composite function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

The graph of $y = f(x)$ is as follows:

[image]

Find $$\int_{-1}^{1} f(1-x^2) dx$$

I tried to solve this through substitution of $u = 1-x^2$, found $dx = \frac{du}{-2x}$ and attempted to adjust the upper and lower bounds of the substitution to attempt to use the graphical area under the function to find my answer. However, when trying to find the upper and lower bounds they both equal $0$, so this cannot work.

Comment: Hint : $f(x) = 2(1-|x|)$ over $[-1,1]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $-1\le x\le1$, then $0\le x^2\le1$ and $0\le1- x^2\le1$!

If $0\le t\le1$, $f(t)=2-2t$. This can be easily seen from the graph.

So, $f(1-x^2)=2-2(1-x^2)=2x^2$ when $-1\le x\le1$.

Comment: I think I'm a bit lost regarding what you've done from Line 1 to Line 2, could you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: How about now, @bio?

Comment: Ah right, yes very obvious in hindsight thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just to correct your substitution, it is totally doable and you are falling into a common pitfall. You can do $u = 1-x^2$ i.e $du = -2x dx$. However you have to be careful because the relation $x= \pm \sqrt{1-u}$ lead to $dx = -\frac{du}{\pm 2\sqrt{1-u}}$ and the $\pm$ sign is absolutely important because it is not constant over the integral interval $[-1,1]$.

Indeed, on $[-1,0]$, $x$ is negative and therefore  $x= - \sqrt{1-u}$ . On $[0,1]$, $x$ is positive and therefore  $x= + \sqrt{1-u}$.

You finally obtain
\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^1 f(1-x^2) dx &= \int_{-1}^0 f(1-x^2) dx +  \int_{0}^1 f(1-x^2) dx \\
&=  +\int_{0}^1 \frac{f(u)}{2\sqrt{1-u}} du -  \int_{1}^0 \frac{f(u)}{2\sqrt{1-u}} du \\
&= +\int_{0}^1 \frac{f(u)}{2\sqrt{1-u}} du +  \int_{0}^1 \frac{f(u)}{2\sqrt{1-u}} du \\
&= \int_{0}^1 \frac{f(u)}{\sqrt{1-u}} du
\end{align}

But this is not very useful in general as this expression is still complicated and also it's an improper integral because the denominator diverges when $u \to 1$ which makes it more tricky if you are not used to it.

However in our particular case if we use the fact that $f(x) = 2(1-|x|)$ then

$$ 2\int_{0}^1 \frac{1-u}{\sqrt{1-u}} du = 2 \int_{0}^1 \sqrt{1-u } \: du = \frac{4}{3}$$
Which is the expected result.

Still, you will notice that it's much more cumbersome than just integrating $2x^2$ ...